# Fullname formatting in Angular 1.x.x

Tags: html, angularjs-directive, angular1.6

How do I render the full name (firstname + lastname / last name + first name) depending on the locale in Angular 1.x.x. I have "first-name", "last-name" and "locale" as strings

I currently have a list of locales and their full name ordering scheme.
[First + last] or [Last + First]

Controller:

```
$ctrl = this; 
$ctrl.firstName = "John"; 
$ctrl.lastName = "Doe"; 
$ctrl.locale = languageService.langLocale(); 
var fullnameGen = function(firstName, lastName) { 
    var order = getOrder(locale); 
    var fullname = ""; 
    for(ele in order) { 
       switch(ele){ 
          case FIRST_NAME: fullname += firstName; 
          case LAST_NAME: fullname += lastName; 
       }
    } 
} 
$ctrl.fullName = fullNameGen(firstName,lastName);
```

View:

```
<div> Full Name: </div> <div> {{$ctrl.fullName}} </div>
```

Comment: Could you please add example? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I currently have a list of locales and their full name ordering scheme.
First + last or
Last + First
controller:
$ctrl = this;
$ctrl.firstName = "John";
$ctrl.lastName = "Doe";
$ctrl.locale = languageService.langLocale();

var fullnameGen = function(firstName, lastName){
 var order = getOrder(locale);
 var fullname = "";
 for(ele in order){
  switch(ele){
   case FIRST_NAME:
    fullname += firstName;
   case LAST_NAME:
    fullname += lastName;
  }
 }
}
$ctrl.fullName = fullNameGen(firstName,lastName);
view:

<div> Full Name: </div>
<div> {{$ctrl.fullName}} </div>